# R code that iteratively creates a "rank_order" column for every column in a given dataframe

Tags: r, data-munging

Given a data frame such as the following, how do I get a rank order (e.g. integer column ranking the value in order from descending as "1,2,3") column output for every single column without writing out ever single column?

```
df <- data.frame(
  col1 = rnorm(100),
  col2 = rnorm(100),
  col3 = rnorm(100),
  col4 = rnorm(100))
```

rank_col1
rank_col2
rank_col3
etc...

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you want?

```
df <- cbind(df, as.data.frame(apply(df, 2, rank)))
```

Comment: Awesome thank you! I originally tried to iterate over   arrange(V1) %>%
  mutate(Rank = 1:nrow(.)) but it didn't work